# Why std::vector<uint8_t>::insert works 5 times faster than std::copy with MSVC 2015 compiler?

Tags: c++

I have a trivial function that copies a byte block to std::vector:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> v;

void Write(const uint8_t * buffer, size_t count)
{
    //std::copy(buffer, buffer + count, std::back_inserter(v));

    v.insert(v.end(), buffer, buffer + count);
}

v.reserve(<buffer size>);
v.resize(0);

Write(<some buffer>, <buffer size>);
```

if I use `std::vector<uint8_t>::insert` it works 5 times faster than if I use `std::copy`.

I tried to compile this code with MSVC 2015 with enabled and disabled optimization and got the same result.

Looks like something is strange with `std::copy` or `std::back_inserter` implementation.

Comment: What if you use `v.reserve`?

Comment: @ tkausl I use it, see the code.

Comment: To be clear: Your question is why one is slower than the other if you disable all optimizations? Because in that case the answer is "that's neither unreasonable nor unexpected"... Step through with your debugger to find out why exactly it happens if you are really curious.

Comment: Consider providing [mcve], so we could reproduce the issue you are facing, instead of trying to implement the test cases on our own.

Comment: You use it outside of the function. Not sure where exactly "outside of the function" is though.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is relevant but `std::vector::push_back` (via `std::back_inserter`) has to at least check if it needs to re-allocate every time, even if you have called reserve first. `std::vector::insert` only has to check if it needs to re-allocate once.

Comment: @Max Langhof the optimization is irrelevant, I tried to compile this code with MSVC 2015 with enabled and disabled optimization and got the same result.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky You still have not posted a [mcve] that shows exactly what you are doing.   At this point, all we have is your word but no evidence of your claim that one method is "5 times slower".  Post a program that duplicates the scenario you are suggesting, and everyone will be able to test it on Visual Studio, gcc, clang, etc. and then give responses that are not based on guesses.

Comment: The effect seems to be even more severe on [clang](http://quick-bench.com/Hdf2NWmKfV9rwZlfVrwDv3Z6a4U) and [gcc](http://quick-bench.com/MjmCmt6bHGp4DV-cpKyEl-fYqHg).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie see Max Langhof's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a good implementation of `std::vector`, `v.insert(v.end(), buffer, buffer + count);` might be implemented as:

```
size_t count = last-first;
resize(size() + count);
memcpy(data+offset, first, count);
```

`std::copy(buffer, buffer + count, std::back_inserter(v))` on the other hand will be implemented as:

```
while ( first != last )
{
   *output++ = *first++;
}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
while ( first != last )
{
   v.push_back( *first++ );
}
```

or (roughly):

```
while ( first != last )
{
   // push_back should be slightly more efficient than this
   v.resize(v.size() + 1);
   v.back() = *first++;
}
```

Whilst in theory the compiler could optimise the above into a `memcpy` its unlikely to, at best you'll probably get the methods inlined so that you don't have a function call overhead, it'll still be writing one byte at a time whereas a memcpy will normally use vector instructions to copy multiple bytes at once.

Comment: is v.push_back really 5 time slower than memcpy?

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I wouldn't be surprised if it is, there's probably a huge amount of code hidden behind a simple `push_back`

Comment: Please reconsider your explanation in light of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51930042/why-stdvectoruint8-tinsert-works-5-times-faster-than-stdcopy-with-msvc-2?noredirect=1#comment90813448_51930392). Note in particular how neither implementation calls any  functions (other than `memmove` and `new` etc., which are used by both).

Comment: @MaxLanghof he isn't using clang though, he's using MSVC

Comment: Trawling through the godbolt source insert eventually calls `std::_Copy_memmove` with visual studio

Comment: And the std::copy version is just calling the back_insert iterator in a loop.

Comment: @AlanBirtles My point is that your argument for why it is slower is not, generally speaking, correct. Yes, this happens to be the assembly that `MSVC` outputs, but both `clang` and `gcc` show the same effect (see comment on question). However, the latter two do _not_ do what you are suggesting, and the effect is _more_ severe for them. Both resolve `insert` and `copy` to a call-free loop (again, excluding `memmove` etc.), so they demonstrably inline everything to the maximum extent possible. Your explanation does not give a reason why there would be a (larger) speed difference here.

Comment: @AlanBirtles probably that is really so, theoretically the push_back parameter of type uint8_t can be passed as uint64_t if the function is not online.

Answer (score 5):

Standard library implementation is written with performance in mind, but performance is achieved only when optimization is ON.

> ```
> //This reduces the performance dramatically if the optimization is switched off.
> ```

Trying to measure a function performance with optimization OFF is as pointless as [asking ourselves if the law of gravitation would still be true if there were no mass left in the Universe](https://books.google.fr/books?id=FMuiZJ9RTzAC&lpg=PA295&ots=qcbTqPF0en&dq=husserl%20law%20of%20gravitation%20no%20mass&pg=PA295#v=onepage&q=husserl%20law%20of%20gravitation%20no%20mass&f=false).

Comment: cannot see the book you are linking :/

Comment: I tried to compile this code with MSVC 2015 with enabled and disabled optimization and got the same result.

Comment: @user463035818 Its just an off-topic joke: It's a book on logic from german philosopher [Husserl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Husserl) where he actually asks that question (answered positively) and then [conclude](https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/slippery-slope) that, since there exist similar laws for the human psyche, those laws must be as eternal, invariable and fundamental as the laws of science and physics.

Answer (score 3):

The call to `v.insert` is calling a member function of the container. The member function knows how the container is implemented, so it can do things that a more generic algorithm can't do. In particular, when inserting a range of values designated by random-access iterators into a vector, the implementation knows how many elements are being added, so it can resize the internal storage once and then just copy the elements.

The call to `std::copy` with an insert-iterator, on the other hand, has to call `insert` for each element. It can't preallocate, because `std::copy` works with sequences, not containers; it doesn't know how to adjust the size of the container. So for large insertions into a vector the internal storage gets resized each time the vector is full and a new insertion is needed. The overhead of that reallocation is amortized constant time, but the constant is much larger than the constant when only one resizing is done.

With the call to `reserve` (which I overlooked, thanks, @ChrisDrew), the overhead of reallocating is not as significant. But the implementation of `insert` knows how many values are being copied, and it knows that those values are contiguous in memory (because the iterator is a pointer), and it knows that the values are trivially copyable, so it will use `std::memcpy` to blast the bits in all at once. With `std::copy`, none of that applies; the back inserter has to check whether a reallocation is necessary, and that code can't be optimized out, so you end up with a loop that copies an element at a time, checking for the end of the allocated space for each element. That's much more expensive than a plain `std::memcpy`.

In general, the more the algorithm knows about the internals of the data structure that it's accessing, the faster it can be. STL algorithms are generic, and the cost of that genericity can be more overhead than a that of a container-specific algorithm.

Comment: reserve is not called, because the vector initial capacity is large enough.

Comment: I sort of disagree with the "`copy` can't know the things `insert` can". In latest `clang`, neither version relies on `memcpy` [1](https://godbolt.org/g/5yrhmp) [2](https://godbolt.org/g/WGPAu7) for the actual copying (both use several `memmove`), but one of them is more aggressive on the unrolling (or so I think). Note the structural similarity of the assembly. This is all templated code, so with proper inlining and optimization, both functions should theoretically be able to achieve the same performance regardless of being a member or free/generic function.

Comment: @MaxLanghof -- I look forward to seeing your explanation for the reported performance discrepancy.